# xcodebuild throws No such file or directory on jenkins shell script

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, jenkins

This is the shell script:

```
usr/bin/xcodebuild -target test -project /Users/Shared/Sai/Documents/test/test.xcodeproj -configuration Release clean build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/Shared/Sai/Documents/app "CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone Developer: Sai (5K2MBOL52K)"
```

It was working earlier suddenly it stopped working.

I searched on the internet and the syntax is right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward slash is missing (/)

It should be `/usr/bin/xcodebuild`